# Following Node.js hello-world tutorial, cannot delete cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I tried following the official hello-world tutorial for google container engine, using node.js, which worked fine. Except for the end, deleting the cluster. How do I add these permissions? I could find a way to add developer permissions, but not cloudservices permissions. Its also strange that I can create the cluster from the cmdline, but not delete it... I did manage to kill the worker instance from the compute engine web console, I think, but the container cluster is still visible. This is the error:

```
    $ gcloud container clusters delete hello-world
The following clusters will be deleted.
 - [hello-world] in [us-central1-f]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?

Deleting cluster hello-world...done.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.delete) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Operation [<Operation
 name: u'operation-1443093077789-c0cb741d'
 operationType: OperationTypeValueValuesEnum(DELETE_CLUSTER, 2)
 selfLink: u'https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/28547436xxx/zones/us-central1-f/operations/operation-1443093077789-c0cb741d'
 status: StatusValueValuesEnum(DONE, 3)
 statusMessage: u'"28547436xxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com" does not have edit permissions on project "mytest".'
 targetLink: u'https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/28547436xxx/zones/us-central1-f/clusters/hello-world'
 zone: u'us-central1-f'>] finished with error: "28547436xxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com" does not have edit permissions on project "mytest".
```

Answer (score 0):

The message `"28547436xxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com" does not have edit permissions on project "mytest"` indicates that you've modified one of the default service accounts in your project -- unfortunately, the one that Container Engine uses to authenticate to other Cloud Platform services to be able to do things like create and delete VMs on your behalf.

You should be able to re-add permissions to that service account from the Developers Console on the Permissions page. After that, deleting the cluster should succeed.

Comment: thanks! The interesting part here is that I just followed the recipe in the tutorial which uses he command line, so the permission was probably there as it was able to create the containers. I did not do anything else in this hour, certainly not deleting any permissions. But now it should be just missing? I also went to the permission page, but can only see service accounts that end in developer.gserviceaccount.com, never anything with cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com. I can add new service accounts in API & auth -> credentials, but again its just developer, not cloudservices. Other ideas?